# Js binding for large rust object using wasm-bindgen

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I want to write a vscode extension that displays the content of a large binary file, written with `bincode`:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyValue {
    pub name: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub data: HashMap<String, MyValue>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn dump(&self, filename: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
        let file = File::create(filename).map_err(|msg| msg.to_string())?;
        let writer = BufWriter::new(file);
        bincode::serialize_into(writer, self).map_err(|msg| msg.to_string())
    }

    pub fn load(filename: &str) -> Result<Self, String> {
        let file = File::open(filename).map_err(|msg| msg.to_string())?;
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        bincode::deserialize_from::<BufReader<_>, Self>(reader).map_err(|msg| msg.to_string())
    }
}
```

Therefore there is a wasm binding:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct PyMyStruct {
    inner: Arc<MyStruct>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl PyMyStruct {
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::new(MyStruct::load(filename).unwrap()),
        }
    }

    pub fn header(self) -> Array {
        let keys = Array::new();
        for key in self.inner.data.keys() {
            keys.push(&JsValue::from_str(key));
        }
        keys
    }

    pub fn value(&self, name: &str) -> JsValue {
        if let Some(value) = self.inner.data.get(name) {
            JsValue::from_serde(value).unwrap_or(JsValue::NULL)
        } else {
            JsValue::NULL
        }
    }
}
```

which provides a simple interface to the JavaScript world in order to access the content of that file.
Using `Arc` in order to prevent expensive unintended memory copy when handling on the JavaScript side.
(It might look strange that `keys` is not marked as mutable but the rust compiler recomended that way)

When running the test code:

```js
const {PyMyStruct} = require("./corejs.js");

let obj = new PyMyStruct("../../dump.spb")
console.log(obj.header())
```

you get the error message:

> Error: null pointer passed to rust

Does someone know how to handle this use case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by using https://neon-bindings.com instead of compiling the API to web-assembly.

The binding here looks as follow:

```rust
use core;
use std::rc::Rc;
use neon::prelude::*;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    inner: Rc<core::MyStruct>,
}

declare_types! {
    pub class JsMyStruct for MyStruct {
        init(mut cx) {
            let filename = cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?.value();

            match core::MyStruct::load(&filename) {
                Ok(inner) => return Ok(MyStruct{
                    inner: Rc::new(inner)
                }),
                Err(msg) => {
                    panic!("{}", msg)
                }
            }
        }

        method header(mut cx) {
            let this = cx.this();
            let container = {
                let guard = cx.lock();
                let this = this.borrow(&guard);
                (*this).clone()
            };
            let keys = container.inner.data.keys().collect::<Vec<_>>();
            let js_array = JsArray::new(&mut cx, keys.len() as u32);
            for (i, obj) in keys.into_iter().enumerate() {
                let js_string = cx.string(obj);
                js_array.set(&mut cx, i as u32, js_string).unwrap();
            }
            Ok(js_array.upcast())
        }

        method value(mut cx) {
            let key = cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?.value();
            let this = cx.this();
            let container = {
                let guard = cx.lock();
                let this = this.borrow(&guard);
                (*this).clone()
            };
            if let Some(data) = container.inner.data.get(&key) {
                return Ok(neon_serde::to_value(&mut cx, data)?);
            } else {
                panic!("No value for key \"{}\" available", key);
            }
        }
    }
}

register_module!(mut m, {
    m.export_class::<JsMyStruct>("MyStruct")?;
    Ok(())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are using `new PyMyStruct()` instead of `PyMyStruct.new()`. In wasm-bindgen's debug mode you will get an error about this at runtime. Using `.new()` will fix your issue:

```js
let obj = PyMyStruct.new("../../dump.spb")
```

If you add the [`#[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]`](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-js-imports/constructor.html) annotation to the `new` method, then  `new PyMyStruct()` will work as well:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
impl PyMyStruct {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: 1,
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is fine:

```js
let obj = new PyMyStruct("../../dump.spb")
```

Comment: WIth your first suggestion I get:
```
let obj = PyMyStruct("../../dump.spb").new()
          ^
TypeError: Class constructor PyMyStruct cannot be invoked without 'new'
```
But with ` #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]` it works.

Comment: Unfortunately: There are still 2 problems remaining:

1. You can only call a method of the object once. The second time you get still *Error: null pointer passed to rust*

2. Rust is not able to open a local file when running in wasm, even when in Node.js.

Comment: @Matthias I updated my answer to fix your first error